# unable to update number input type using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to enter value to number input type text box with pattern using `sendKeys` method, since `sendKeys` only support string data type. Is there any other way i achieve this?

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="textFieldLength">
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendKeys` can enter data into numeric input.
You can do it just passing number, converted to `String`.

```java
int number = 42;
element.sendKeys(String.valueOf(number));
```

you can test it by executing code below

```java
WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.get("https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-08-16.html");
WebElement numInput = wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ById("textFieldLength")));
int number = 52;
numInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(number));
```

Comment: i dont this will work, since the input has pattern matching.

Comment: @jijeshvu I tested it there by defining you element and it works with you element 
`    WebElement numberInput = wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ById("textFieldLength")));
        int number = 52;
        numberInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(number));`

Comment: if it doesn't work for you - so you provided wrong element in your question.

Comment: @jijeshvu I provided you link for testing) if it still doesn't work, you can save your html on that resource and provide me a link. Usage of `JavascriptExecutor` is not recommended instead of cases when you can't do action with native Selenium methods.

Comment: Where is your link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript Executor in Selenium to set the value of the input field directly, bypassing the sendKeys method. This allows you to work with numeric values while still adhering to the pattern attribute.

```
WebElement numberInput = driver.findElement(By.id("textFieldLength"));
String valueToSet = "123"; 
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", numberInput, valueToSet);
```

Comment: what is this `"arguments[0].value = arguments[1]"` means?

Comment: The purpose of this JavaScript code is to change the value of an HTML element named "numberInput" to "valueToSet" by executing JavaScript through the WebDriver.

Comment: im getting IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type

Comment: if your code waiting String but u entered int u get IllegalArgumentException like illegal type